# i need this to start on page load and loop infinitely

Tags: jquery, loops, animation, onload

I need this to start on page load and loop infinitely. Here's what I have so far.

```
$(document).ready(function slideshow(){
    $('#slide1').show(500).delay(500).animate({width:'240px'}).delay(500).animate({height:'50px', width:'410px'}).delay(1500).hide(500);
    $('#slide2').delay(4000).show(500).delay(500).animate({width:'150px'});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use [`setInterval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)` to call repeatedly

> The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression
>   at specified intervals (in milliseconds)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
     //your code here
}, 5000);
});
```

This will repeat for every 5 seconds

Comment: i've tried setInterval and setTimeout but they both mess up the order of the animations once it starts looping. any fixes for this?

Answer (score 0):

@PSR's answer helps if you're always sure you want to repeat each 5 seconds.

Another way would be to write what's called a recursive function: a function that calls itself. This allows you to start a new animation the moment all current animations are done.

```
$(document).ready(function slideshow(){
    var animationsToComplete = 2,
    animationsCompleted =0;

    //in your specific example you could omit this and only have a callback on the animation
    //that takes the longest time, but to be a bit more generic, you could use the folowing
    //which tests if all animations are completed and if so, immediately starts a new one.
    var conditionalRecursiveCall = function(){
      if(++animationsCompleted % animationsToComplete == 0){
         recFn();
      }
    }

    var recFn = function(){
      $('#slide1').show(500).delay(500).animate({width:'240px'}).delay(500).animate({height:'50px', width:'410px'}).delay(1500).hide(500, conditionalRecursiveCall)
      $('#slide2').delay(4000).show(500).delay(500).animate({width:'150px'}, 400, 'swing',conditionalRecursiveCall);
    }  

    recFn();
});
```

Comment: this one loops but the order of the animation is messed up when it does! any fixes?

Comment: which order? There shouldn't be a relationship beween `slide1` and `slide2` right? As for correctly looping an animation for,say, `slide1` (the same holds for `slide2`) you need to make sure the starting css of the 2nd,.. nth iteration is the same as the starting css of the first iteration. (i.e.: You need to reset to `display: none` probably, bc you're calling `show` and you need to reset to the `width` and `height` of the element prior to the animation started. Same goes for `slide2` as described.

Comment: hmm i'll try it out, thanks for sticking with this, appreciate it!